# How to know if a given function graphs any points within a given range

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If a given a function, let's say $2x^2-3=y$, and a range, for example $0<x<1$ and $0<y<1$, how can we know if the graph of the function plots a point inside this range, aside from endlessly searching for one.

Comment: This is essentially the same question as "how do I graph a function?", which is a process one learns alongside algebra. In this example, the function $2x^2-3$ is increasing for positive $x$, so it's not hard to find the entire range of that function as $x$ goes from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: Find derivatives in reference to x and find solutions for x when zero. Calculate the x's of the extreme cases and compare them to the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways to answer this question depending on how much math you know. In general, as said in the comments answering these types of questions will be very similar to graphing, it all comes down to understanding the behaviour of the function. In this example we have a quadratic, which is already in vertex form.

Notice that when $x > y \geq 0$ we have $x^2 > y^2$ and when $0 \geq y > x $ we also have $x^2 > y^2$. Because of this we can see that $y=2x^2-3$ is increasing for positive x, and decreasing for negative x.

So all we need to do is check the values at the extremes. For $x=0$ we have $y=0$ and for $x=1$ we have $y=1$. since this is an increasing function in this interval, we know that for all $x$ in the interval $(0,1)$ $y$ will also be in the interval $(0,1)$.

Comment: This is not a general solution. Playing with every function makes it an ineffective solution.

Comment: Read the tagged subject in the post, it says algebra-precalculus. So your solution involving derivatives is wrong. This is not a general solution, but a general solution is not possible nor expected in precalc. What I demonstrate here is how to use knowledge about the function to solve this question, which is the "general" precalculus solution.